# In coding the math, how would you calculate how many times the size of one cities population is to another? Like Quebec. pop to Copenhagan pop?

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem, ratio

I have a Quebec population : $8,164,361$

And Copenhagen population : $775,033$

---

How would I be able to determine the how many times the size of one is to another?

For example I know for Quebec the inclusive inverse would read:

Quebec is $1.0$ times the size of Quebec

and then for two other city populations it should read like:

Beijing is $31.56334$ times the size of Washington D.C.

I imagine this is very simple math. Would I just divide one by the other if so which one goes in the denominator and numerator? Or is there something more to this than meets the eye.

Thank you

Comment: Quebec's population is $\dfrac{8164361}{775033.} = 10.5$ times larger than Copenhagen.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

The simpler and standard way is to calculate the following ratio

$$\frac{8164361}{775033}\approx 10.5$$

and say that Quebec, as population, is 10 times larger than Copenaghen.

As an alternative we can take for example

$$\frac{8164361-775033}{8164361}\approx 0.905=90.5\%$$

and say that Copenaghen has $90.5\%$ poplation less than Quebec or

$$\frac{8164361-775033}{775033}\approx 9.53=953\%$$

and say that Quebec has 953% more pupulation than Copenaghen.

Comment: So it will be whatever the larger one is over and the smaller. Therefore I will have to make an if statement to check which is larger and put that one on top and the lower at the bottom. Is that right?

Comment: It dependes upon what you want refer to. If you want tell that one is x time larger than the oder yes you should put the greater above. The if could be laso be made at the end inverting the ratio if it is less than 1 but maybe this is not so important.

Comment: I want to have it how I showed in the example with Beijing being 31.5 times the size of DC. And then D.C being 0.03 times the size of Beijing.

Comment: Yes it is correct Beijing being 31.5 times the size of DC and DC $\frac1{31.5}\approx 0.03$  the size of Beijing.

Comment: Okay so that's DC's population divided by Beijing's population. So: 700000/21500000 = 0.032558. So when I compare DC against Beijing it should be the one in question in the numerator against the one being compared to in denominator?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Answer (score 0):

City $A$'s population is $\dfrac{p_A}{p_B}$ times the size of that of city $B$, where $p_A$ and $p_B$ denote the population of cities $A$ and $B$ respectively.